# PHP MySQL search with optional fields

Tags: php, sql, search

I am trying to create a form that a user can enter information in and then search a table that matches this query. I want the information entered to be optional (not all fields need to be completed). I have the first 'if' working for just the floor and flatno but can not get the second 'if with the addition of the 'status' added to the query.

I know about the security issues in my code but only want to use this on an internal server as a guide for myself.

```
<?php


// if there is a value in the floor and flatno field then do this:
    if (!empty($_POST['Floor']) && (!empty($_POST['flatno']))) 
{
    require 'connectdb.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM issuelog WHERE floor='$_POST[Floor]' AND flatnumber='$_POST[flatno]'");
}   

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

include( "searchoutputform.php" );
  }

// second if - if there is something in the floor, flatno and status field then do this:

 elseif (!empty($_POST['Floor']) && (!empty($_POST['flatno'] && (!empty($_POST['status'])))))
{
    require 'connectdb.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM issuelog WHERE floor='$_POST[Floor]' AND flatnumber='$_POST[flatno]' AND status='$_POST[status]'");
}   

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

include( "searchoutputform.php" );
  }
endif;

// CLOSE CONNECTION TO DATABASE 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Update: I have removed all of the requests to connect so there is only 1 now! I am getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ') (this is based on the second if)

Comment: How many times do you `require 'connectdb.php';` throughout??? Please, basic debugging is down to _you_, not us.

Comment: Way (too (many (parenthesis)))

Comment: If you add an update to say you've modified the code, please also modify the code we can see, otherwise it is rather confusing!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Your first if will always execute if both those values are there, your elseif will not execute then. Simply change your elseif to another if

```
if (!empty($_POST['Floor']) && !empty($_POST['flatno'] && !empty($_POST['status']))
{
//...
}
```

**Why so?**  Here's why

```
   if(1==1 && 2==2)
   {
      echo "first if";
   }
   elseif(1==1 && 2==2 && 3==3)
   {
     echo "this one will not execute even though the condition is true, due to elseif";
   }
   if(1==1 && 2==2 && 3==3)
   {
     echo "Now this one will work";
   }
```

That's one basic *fix*, but you should simplify the logic and build the query then append values to it if they are present.

And you have some extra parenthesis, and you have some extra includes :)